# Regex pattern matching

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm a complete newb when it comes to regex and I need a way to match the following pattern:

```
0hv05d_1a8198c8c430c2333fd6e49863f59f60_d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e_3600_3_25
```

Explained:

There are 6 sections separated by underscores. First section is always 6 [a-zA-Z0-9] characters. Second and third sections are MD5 hashes, so they will always be 32 [a-zA-Z0-9] characters each. Last 3 sections can only be numbers.

I'm using PHP preg_match to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try reading this page: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html from start to finish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
<?php
$string = '0hv05d_1a8198c8c430c2333fd6e49863f59f60_d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e_3600_3_25';
if (preg_match('/([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})_([a-fA-F0-9]{32})_([a-fA-F0-9]{32})_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)/',$string,$match)) {
    print_r( $match );
}
?>
```

Comment: Works great, except if I add letters in between number in the last three sections, it still comes up positive if I don't return the values into $match. Either case, this is sufficient for what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @Vitality Isikov That is strange. I can not explain it. You're welcome!

Answer (score 8):

Here's the shortest I can make it, based on your (somewhat incomplete) specifications:

```
preg_match('/[a-z\d]{6}(?:_[a-f\d]{32}){2}(?:_\d+){3}/i', $string);
```

This will match exactly six instances of a letter or digit; followed by an underscore and 32 hexadecimal digits, twice; followed by an underscore and any number of digits, 3 times. The `/i` at the end puts it into case-insensitive mode.

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = "0hv05d_1a8198c8c430c2333fd6e49863f59f60_d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e_3600_3_25";
if (preg_match('/^([a-z0-9]{6})_([a-f0-9]{32})_([a-f0-9]{32})_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)$/i', $string, $matches))
{
    echo "Match!<br />\n";
    echo "First: ".$matches[1]."<br />\n";
    echo "MD5 hashes: ".$matches[2]. " - ".$matches[3]."<br />\n";
    echo "numbers: ".$matches[4]. " - ".$matches[5]. " - ".$matches[6]."<br />\n";
}
```

**notes:**

- md5 are just [a-f0-9], not [a-z0-9].
- I put /i to case insensitive matches,
  instead of specifying [a-zA-Z] in
  every part.

Comment: I've edited it several times, if still don't work, substitute \d by [0-9] (I'm editing it now)

Comment: I've put that the whole text you are trying to match is the pattern you said. If you need to match that pattern inside a larger text, please remove the `^` at the beginning of the pattern and the `$` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Edit- To be more complete you could do this:

```
if (preg_match('/[a-z0-9]{6}_[a-f0-9]{32}_[a-f0-9]{32}_\d+_\d+_\d+/i', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

I also to make it more concise replased [0-9] with the \d class, changed the matching of MD5 to just [a-f0-9], and I also changed [a-zA-Z0-9] to [a-z0-9] and included the `/i` for case insensitive.

If you really wanted to the expression could also be rewritten as:

`/[a-z0-9]{6}(?:_[a-f0-9]{32}){2}(?:_\d+){3}/i`

Answer (score 0):

`[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}_[a-f0-9]{32}_[a-f0-9]{32}_[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+`

ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

also, since php using PCRE (Pearl Compatible Regular Expressions) you can use this nifty cheat sheet: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/